# Remove duplicates based on one column and keep latest entry in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, scripting

I was working on some automation and wanted to remove the duplicate rows in my google sheet by comparing it on basis of 3rd column. I found one code which is working flawlessly but it does not remove the old entry in sheet, it removes the latest one. I wanted to keep the latest one from the duplicates.

This is the code which I found for appscript by [Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper):

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dt=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var uA=[];
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i<dt.length;i++) {
    if(uA.indexOf(dt[i][2])==-1) {
      uA.push(dt[i][2]);
    }else{
      sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me with the code which does the same work "removing duplicate rows (Keeps latest entry removes the old entry) based on column" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `I wanted to keep the latest one from the duplicates.`, when the latest one is the last row, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dt = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var uA = [];
  for (var i = dt.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (uA.indexOf(dt[i][2]) == -1) {
      uA.push(dt[i][2]);
    } else {
      sh.deleteRow(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Mahesh Jandwani Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `It will really help me to improve my automation process, but actually the latest entry isnt in the last row, also there is not only one duplicate row entries present, so I think function will require some more modification.`, I thought that this modified script works for that situation. Can I ask you about the detailed information about the issue? I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Really Sorry for the wrong information provided. The function is working absolutely fine. I just tried it with my format and my old rows from the duplicates were removed. Previously I was getting confused in my own sheet format only. Reall sorry for that once again.

Comment: @Mahesh Jandwani Thank you for replying and testing it. I could understand that the script worked. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // get values of column C
  var col = sh.getDataRange().getValues().map(x => x[2]);

  // get indexes of duplicated values in the column
  var duplicates = col.map((x,i) => 
    col.slice(i+1).includes(x) ? i+1 : '').filter(String); 

  // remove rows by the indexes
  duplicates.reverse().forEach(x => sh.deleteRow(x));
}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

**Update**

If there will some glitches it makes sense to add the command `flush()` after every `deleteRow()`. The last line of the code should be like this:

```
  // remove rows by the indexes
  duplicates.reverse().forEach(x => { sh.deleteRow(x); SpreadsheetApp.flush() });
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yuri, This is what I was looking for. My problem is fully solved now and function is working flawlessly. Thanks once again !!

Comment: Well. Conrats! But if the 'latest' rows aren't the last ones it's need another approach. This code keeps the last rows.

Comment: Basically my script functioning is that it is fetching json data from an api and embedding all that into each row one by one into the google sheets with the help of appscript. Suppose i ran my script and it fetched 100 rows into the sheet. After a few days I did the same thing and sheet filled again 100 rows of same data with slight update in it from row 101 to 200. Now I wanted to remove the duplicates but the old entries which were present in 1 to 100 rows. So do you think it ll work right in that scenario ? As per your advise above, I think it will definitely work.

Comment: From your description it should work. It will remove all duplicates (based on column B) from the top rows and keep in the last (bottom) rows. But there can be another problem: `deleteRow()` is a time consuming operation. It sometimes can get glitches if there are too many cells to process. In this case it makes sense to add `spreadsheet.flush()` command after every `deleteRow()`.

Comment: So the last line of function becomes something like this ?

duplicates.reverse().forEach(x => spreadhsheet.flush(x));

Comment: Almost. ) I've added the example in my answer.

Comment: And actually if you have no formulas in the table and there is no tricky formating you can do the job much much faster without the `deleteRow()`. You can grab all the data from the sheet as an 2D-array, make changes in the memory, clear the sheet, and put the new 2D-array back on the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified retaining all other rows while eliminating duplicates from column A.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
 // Get the reference to the active sheet.
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 // Get all the data from the sheet.
 var dt = sh.getRange("A:A").getValues(); // Only fetch data from Column A
 // Create an array to store unique values from Column A.
 var uA = [];
 // Loop through each cell in Column A.
 for (var i = 0; i < dt.length; i++) {
 // Check if the value in Column A is not in the unique array.
 if (uA.indexOf(dt[i][0]) == -1) {
 // If not found, add it to the unique array.
 uA.push(dt[i][0]);
 } else {
       // If found, clear the cell.
          sh.getRange(i + 1, 1).setValue('');
       }
 }
}
```